# JS Как привязать функцию на выполнение после обработки другой функции?

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть необходимость выполнить функцию, после выполнения первой функции, но когда первая будет завершена(и будет ли), отследить сложно. Приведу простой пример что б объяснить сумбур вопроса.

```js
/// WE CAN'T change this elements
const btn = document.getElementById("btn_push");
let sendData = (timeFunc) => { console.log(`Function DONE! It took ${timeFunc} sec`)};
let randomInteger = (min, max) => {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand);
}
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  const time = randomInteger(1000, 4000);
  setTimeout(sendData(time), time); 
});

/// OWN elements


let secondFunction = () => { console.log(`This function done after server get data`)};
```

Предположим имеется функция отправляющая данные на сервер `sendData()` по нажатию на кнопку. Сколько она будет выполняться (проводить валидации, общаться с другими API и тд.) нам не известно. Нам известно только её название, и то, что выполнение повешено на клик. Вопрос, как выполнить `secondFunction()` по завершению выполнения первой функции? *Вторая функция может вызываться совершенно с другого `js` файла этого же html документа. Возможно ли это как-то отловить, что она завершила действие?

PS Если б это всё было в одном js и можно б было переписать вызов первой функции, то делалось бы через [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), но этого нету.

Comment: Допустим: в HTML создаем элемент(любой, скрытый) и на него рядом со второй функцией вешам обработчик события(имя события мы можем придумать любое) - допустим '*onFncEnd*'. Соответственно, когда первая завершена(ведь где то у нее есть конец), фукнция должна задиспейчить событие в элемент `.dispatchEvent('onFncEnc')`, а далее сработает слушатель и запустит вторую фукнцию. Подробнее про [пользовательские события](https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events)

Comment: так в том и вопрос, что б знать, что функция завершина? Как это отловить ? Можете показать на примере.. когда надо стартовать `secondFunction()`

Comment: Покажите реальную вашу фукнцию и можно будет сказать, где у нее конец. Вообще, фукнции заканчиваются, обычно, в конце кода. Если это промисы, то это последняя строка последнего `.then()` условно. Сложнее, если фукнция вызывает и не дожидается другие асинхронные фукнции.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод setTimeout для запуска функции secondFunction после выполнения функции sendData. Вы можете передать функцию sendData в качестве аргумента в setTimeout, а затем в теле функции sendData вызвать secondFunction.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  const time = randomInteger(1000, 4000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    sendData(time);
    secondFunction();
  }, time); 
});
```

Так же Вы можете использовать события, которые генерирует sendData(Event), и подписать secondFunction на это событие. Таким образом, secondFunction будет выполнятся только после того, как sendData генерирует событие.

```
document.addEventListener('sendDataEvent', secondFunction);
let sendData = (timeFunc) => { 
  console.log(`Function DONE! It took ${timeFunc} sec`);
  document.dispatchEvent(new Event('sendDataEvent'));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не переписать функцию?

```
const oldFunc = btn.onclick;

btn.onclick = function(e) {
    const data = oldFunc(e);
    sencodFunction();
    return data;
    //или
    setTimeout(sencodFunction, 200)
    return oldFunc(e);
}
```

Comment: потому-что закрыт доступ к исправлению чужих ф-ций. Можно добавлять что-то новое, но не ломать контекст и порядок вывода.